# How to configure python32 interpreter under cygwin for eclipse in window ?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

I've seen new cygwin for window contains python3.2 files.

Where is the `python3.2.exe` file under cygwin on window?  I need it to configure interpreter for Eclipse in window, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in `/usr/bin`, or in windows as `{Cygwin Install directory}\bin`. For example: `D:\Cygwin\bin\`

Ensure that you run `python3.2.exe` within the Cygwin emulation layer.

Comment: but I am not able to find python3.2.exe

Comment: Did you install the Python3 package? If not, run `Setup.exe` and in the Select Packages screen open up the Python, and install Python3.